# CSS/JavaScript - Adding the :focus state when an element is hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a navigation bar using standard Bootstrap 3 classes and structure, recently I wanted to see if you could open the drop down menus on hover.

I did some searching and found this snippet:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

This opens the menu on hover, which is great (without having to toggle `.dropdown-toggle`

My issue is that my `.dropdown-toggle` has a `focus` state, which only happens when focus is given to the element, so when I hover and the menu opens my hover state is never applied, as I do not have to click on the top menu item anymore.

So the question is: is there a way to force the `:focus` state when `:hover` is active?

I tried to do this:

```
.dropdown:hover #home .dropdown-toggle:focus{
    background: #00aaff;
    border: #00aaff 1px solid;
}
```

So basically on hover add styles to the focus, but I think what I actually need to do is add the `:focus` class on `:hover` so is this more a JavaScript thing?

Comment: have you tried just removing `:focus`, so you have `.dropdown:hover #home .dropdown-toggle {`?

Comment: You cannot force `:focus` via pure CSS; you would have to do so via JavaScript, through the `element.focus()` method.

Comment: This is good to know as it points me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function(){
  $('#home .dropdown-toggle').focus();
});
```

And in css

```
#home .dropdown-toggle:focus{
   background: #00aaff;
   border: #00aaff 1px solid;
}
```

when the focus is on, the css gets apply.

Comment: This is a good answer, my only question is, could I expand this so that when hover is lost, focus is also lost.

Comment: till when you want to keep the :focus state on the element?

Comment: While I'm hovering the menu, so when I un-hover the menu the focus is lost.

Comment: In my case :focus doesn't seem to work on <li> items, while forcing :focus with dev tools works :/

Answer (score 2):

I see it as 'a JavaScript thing'. You can attach a 'mouseover' event to the menu, which, when triggered, will change the menu's CSS and the CSS of the .dropdown-toggle element.

I do not think it makes a lot of sense to trigger "focus" state for CSS modification if you are using JavaScript (in this particular example, I will use JQuery library).

A simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/matu2vd6/5/

HTML:

```
<div class='dropdown'>My dropdown element.</div>

<div class='dropdown-toggle'>My dropdown-toggle element.</div>
```

JS/JQUERY:

```
let dropDownEl = $(".dropdown");
let dropDownToggleEl = $(".dropdown-toggle");

dropDownEl.on("mouseover", function() {
  dropDownToggleEl.css({"background": "#00aaff",
    "border": "#00aaff 1px solid"});
});
dropDownEl.on("mouseout", function() {
  dropDownToggleEl.css({"background": "transparent",
    "border": "none"});
});
```

Comment: I feel this is also a viable answer, the reason I am changing to the focus state is because the focus state themselves are useful for when not hovering, like when on a tablet. - So I thought, if they exist anyway why not just apply them on hover?